# Should an established business use cheap hosting?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I re-designed a few sites for a marketing & events company, and they are asking me to spear-head a host change because they don't like their current host, so they pay very little.

They have:

- Five static sites (total of about 3GBs of disk space)
- All five sites probably get 20,000+ visitors a month.
- They currently pay $10 a month for shared hosting.
- They have about 15 active e-mail addresses.
- Their servers always go down, and their email always goes down.

They want to switch hosting and are looking into www.hostgator.com . They want to effectively pay the same yet get better results. I have recommended better hosting locally in Toronto that would cost about $50 a month, but with a very reputable company.

As I mainly deal with front-end design, I'm not sure how to best explain to them their best option. Should an established company use cheap ($10/month) hosting? Or is this asking for trouble? Should I politely explain that a company with 15 employees needs to invest more than $100 a year in their web presence?

Comment: This question wasn't initially posted to SO, it was posted to Server Fault (I think). Don't understand the down vote 3.5 years later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a very low amount of visitors so any host should handle it, and space should not be a concern either.  I agree they should invest more but it depends on how critical the sites are to their business, or whether they ARE the business.

It sounds like the current host is unreliable but you can find another host that has more reliability.  1and1, godaddy, ipower are 3 that come to mind and all typically under $100/year but I believe that is per-domain so they might still have to pay about the $50/month you are recommending for the 5 sites.

- SEE: lf=Static&linkOrigin=&linkId=hd.subnav.linuxhosting">http://www.1and1.com/linux-web-hosting?_lf=Static&linkOrigin=&linkId=hd.subnav.linuxhosting
- SEE: http://www.ipower.com/ipower/web-hosting/unix-compare-plans.bml
- SEE: http://www.godaddy.com/products/websites-hosting.aspx?ci=72738

Your question about established company using cheap hosting: sure they can and if the host is not reliable they can find a better one and still stay cheap.

Your question about explaining they need to invest more: that depends on how critical the sites are to their business and their needs.  If just brochureware about their company, and not their actual product, it might be acceptable to them.  If their product is a web application and they are expected to be reliable for their customers, definitely have the talk.  They can get a dedicated server with control panel to manage all their domains, email, etc. for less than $150/month, or leverage the 24/7 support of the vendors I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's effectively just brochureware about their company on the site. Based on your answer, it would seem a reliable shared host (i.e. GoDaddy, 1and1) would function just fine.

Answer (score 3):

20000 visitors a month is only about 27 visitors an hour, or 1 every 2 minutes or so. That's a pretty light load, unless you're doing some real heavy-duty server-side processing.

As far as the user load goes, I think the basic shared hosting setup is probably sufficient. As an example, Go Daddy's setup is like $7.00 a month (US) and is pretty reliable.  I've got a few clients hosting their sites there and we've had very few problems.  I've also heard pretty good things about HostGator and their prices are similar.

If you want to go to a VPS (Virtual Private Server) setup, you don't need to spend $100/month. They start off at about $20.00 or so a month for a relatively basic setup, and go up from there depending on things like RAM and disk space.

The biggest advantage to a VPS might be the flexibility to install whatever additional software you want, something you can't do with most shared hosting setups.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Will speeds be affected if all five of their static domains are on one $10/month plan? Aka, if www.website1.com is being viewed, that will slow down website2.com, website3.com, etc as well?

Comment: The only thing that really affects speed is the number of concurrent requests, not how many domains they're spread across.  That is, 5 requests for the same domain is basically the same load as 1 request each for 5 domains.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of site they're running, or more precisely, how much money they *gain* by having a web presence.

If they're running a basic site that says who they are, what they do, and how to contact them, then they probably don't need decent hosting. 20k visits per month isn't much, so it's certainly not worth spending a lot of money on. In fact, you're probably better off spending the money on getting a nice professional redesign every 2-3 years or so, to keep the company image up to date.

If they're running an e-commerce site, where some of their orders come directly from their site, they should definitely invest more in their hosting. Keep in mind that for every hit that occurs during hosting downtime, you lose a potential customer. Paying $50 per month for hosting is good value for money if you're making $100 per month or more from online orders, which I hope would be the case for a successful business.

If they're looking to gain a bigger online audience, perhaps you should convince them to spend some money on an SEO campaign, and set aside money for the extra hits when your current hosting plan can't cope with the load.